# Rename folders/files whose delete permission is blocked

Tags: windows-server-2008, rename, ntfs, user-permissions

I have a shared folder in my network where a lot of users access and store their documents. I'm admin of this shared folder and I've denied delete permissions for all other users.
The problem starts when a user creates a new folder and tries to rename it.
Windows says "Access denied"
I'm assuming that this might be because I've denied delete permissions for that user.
(Since Rename=Delete+CreateFolderWithNewName)

Is there any way so that I can keep the delete permissions intact, and allow the user to rename his files/folders?

Or any other workarounds?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 and NTFS file system.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should look into the folder design / your setup.

A kind of Work around, is to give "Delete" and "Delete subfolders and files" rights to "CREATOR OWNER", then the creator of the file or folder is able to rename (and delete) his own files/folders.

Maybe you could Schedule a nightly powershell script (not privided) which takes ownership of all files and folders, to restrict owners from future renaming/deletion of files

Answer (score 0):

If they creating in the shared folder it will inherit the permissions of the shared folder. You would need to break inheritance and allow delete permissions on the sub folder to achieve what you want.

There are two managable solutions if there are alot of folders created in the root.

1. Write a service/application to do that for you.
2. Create a series of folders (perhaps person/team based) in the folder, change the permissions on them and tell users to store files in there.